# In the linux top program, what does the z option indicate

Tags: top, process-monitoring

I'm trying to understand the top program better, and I don't really get the 'z' option which highlights all running processes.

Wouldn't all processes in top be considered running? 
In what context would a process be listed in top but not considered running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running in this case means "on cpu", i.e., calculations are being performed. Other processes will be sleeping, meaning they are "off cpu", i.e., nothing is being calculated on their behalf, they are waiting for something.

Comment: Is sleeping the same thing as being in a blocked state ie. they are waiting for IO?

Comment: A process that is blocked on I/O is in a state known as "uninteruptable sleep", which is not the same state as sleeping. In the context of this question, a process in iowait I don't think will show as running, but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

Think "currently active" or "running right now".  Top is based on resources used.  I may have just completed a resource intensive task so that task will appear in the list because it used a lot resources even though the task is idle now.  With top running, try toggling the display with the "i" key to show and hide idle tasks.

Which *nix are you using?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu